# Where's the source code to the native PDF viewer in Google Chrome?

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, chromium

Can't seem to find it in trunk. Is this actually part of the open-source Chromium project? Or is the source to this not actually released? Only mention I could find:

http://www.listware.net/201007/chromium-discuss/93274-chromium-discuss-chrome-pdf-viewer-source.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Fetch it with Git:

- `$ git clone https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium`

View and contribute:

- https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/master (Source browser)
- https://pdfium.googlesource.com/pdfium/+/master/LICENSE (BSD 3-clause)
- https://code.google.com/p/pdfium/ (Bug-tracker)

Answer (score 3):

Chromium just automatically embeds a page with PDF, the custom plugin is bundled up with Chrome. Adobe and Google has some mutual agreement:

You can right click and inspect the PDF Native Viewer to see  yourself, you will see something like the following:

```
<html>
<body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" bgcolor="rgb(38,38,38)">
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name="plugin" src="http://path/to/file.pdf" type="application/pdf">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just cite a snippet of the [Chromium wiki](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/ChromiumBrowserVsGoogleChrome) (last updated on Nov 20, 2012):

> The Chrome PDF plugin uses 3rd-party non-free code; no Free Software PDF plugin exists that supports all the PDF features we'd like (such as filling in forms). :(

Comment: As of 2014, it's open source: http://www.itproportal.com/2014/06/19/google-throws-pdfium-into-the-open-source-community/

Answer (score -3):

It is closed-source, just as native Flash plugin.

Comment: any idea what PDF technology it uses?

Comment: @Dwight Kelly, It is using google 's skia graphics library, Skia can draw directly on pdf. http://code.google.com/p/skia/

Comment: skia is can draw TO PDF, what does Google use to render the contents of a PDF?

Comment: Dwight Kelly, some foxit-based solution - http://blog.foxitsoftware.com/foxit-pdf-technology-chosen-for-google-open-source/ and some google pdf viewer was opensourced as https://pdfium.googlesource.com