# Disable the possibility to print a PDF in a browser running on a kiosk-mode computer

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, pdf

I'm developping an application which will be used inside a web browser (Firefox or Chrome).
One part of this app will display a PDF. However, with the standard PDF viewers, there are some functionalities included that I don't want the user to have (e.g. print, save to disk, ...).
I've found [this](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js) great project about a customizable pdf viewer for mozilla. This allows me to restrict the user's possibilities. Now I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve the same in Google Chrome. So far I haven't found anything about customizing the standard PDF viewer of Chrome. Is there anyone who knows a way to do this, or knows a customizable viewer like the one I've found for mozilla? Thank you.

**Update:**

The browser will run in **kiosk mode**, so the user will not have access to any function other than viewing a web page (no address bar, no menu, nothing). Also, no keyboard will be present, since the application will be used on a touch screen.

**Update 2:**

First of all, why has this question been moved from programmers to stackoverflow?? When I ask this type of 'open' questions here, they get closed instantly. Thanks for the downvote. I guess, for people, questions that can't be answered with 3 lines of code are too hard.

Second, concerning the printing of PDF:
I see some people mentioning ways to print PDF files. The user will have none of these options available because:

- There will be no printers available in the eventual setup of the system.
- There will be no keyboard or mouse, only a (limited) touch interface.
- The webpage will not be available from anywhere except the intented location.
- The user  will not be able to access the underlying OS.

Disabling the ability to print is not hard, but I don't want the user to **think** he can print. If the print icon remains on the PDF viewer, the user clicks it and nothing happens, this will lead to frustration and irritation. By showing only the buttons that actually work, will lead to a better experience of using the application.

Comment: Have you tried using CSS to define the print media type to display none?

Comment: pdf.js works fine in Chrome as well. On a web page including pdf.js, downloading the PDF data via `XMLHttpRequest` and giving it to pdf.js should work - the standard PDF viewer doesn't see it. If you are building an extension things will be similar.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why on earth would you want to do that?

Comment: If anyone an access this web application from any computer what you want is not possible.

Comment: Will there be a printer installed? If not then why does it matter. Cut it off with hardware. And kill it with fire.

Comment: How do you prevent people from taking a photo with their cell phone cameras, and printing that?

Comment: @Wladimir Palant: Do you have an example of download a PDF via XMLHttpRequest ?

Comment: @BramW.: No, I don't - but you probably want to [download it as binary data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest#Handling_binary_data).

Comment: Long time ago but basically now the answer is just get your own pdf viewer, here is a page with the info about the source for chromes built in pdf viewer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3692598/wheres-the-source-code-to-the-native-pdf-viewer-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 3):

The URL to the PDF is enough to print and save the file, inside or outside the browser.  The only way to completely prevent the user from having those options is to present the PDF within your own viewer, such as a Flash application (e.g. Scribd).

Comment: I've updated my question. The user will not have access to the URL of the PDF.

Comment: You can trivially take a screenshot and print that. Once it can be displayed, it can be printed. (Print is just a different kind of display.)

Comment: @BramW. If it's in kiosk mode, and the user will have no access to anything other than viewing a web page, why the concern over printing, saving to disk, etc.?

Answer (score 3):

You could implement [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/default.jsp). Customize the UI controls and [convert your PDF](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_converting.jsp) files via command line or other means. Most of this information is in the [FlexPaper docs](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs.htm)

There are parameters to disable functionality and remove the buttons also.

For example

```
{
 PrintToolsVisible : false,
 PrintEnabled : true
}
```

Seems like there is missing some information from the site because according to [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en_US#!searchin/flexpaper/buttons/flexpaper/PiMqV1EYC2g/SmSccpSz3zgJ) it was [in their wiki](http://code.google.com/p/flexpaper/wiki/Parameters) but then got moved [to their web](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/docs_parameters.jsp) site and maybe some information got forgotten but they are clearly in the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Since you say the app will run in kiosk-mode, you are looking at the wrong place to implement this protection. The PDF protections can be broken with specific software.

The kiosk could run in a "read-only" mode, where one can't save files to it (or at most, the files would not survive a reboot).

As for printing, if the user will not have access to the underlying OS, just disable the printing features of the OS (in a Linux system, you would remove CUPS; in Windows, disabling the spooler service would be enough).

Comment: In a windows OS it will be enough to disable the spooler service