# Asp.net c# view pdf without saving or printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I'm new to asp.net and I'm trying to find a way to view the pdf file on the same screen or using the browser's plugin but I need a way to disable the saving option and the print option.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable the possibility to print a PDF in a browser running on a kiosk-mode computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748424/disable-the-possibility-to-print-a-pdf-in-a-browser-running-on-a-kiosk-mode-comp)

Comment: Did the answer help?

Comment: I did prevent printing but I have to prevent the saving too

Comment: It isn't possible @MahmoudYoussef .

Comment: I'm thinking of an approach involving converting the pdf to tiff or to multiple images I already did convert it to tiff and then I'm looking for a way to preview it but I have to use an Image tag in html so I need to save each file on it's own then open it by creating two buttons ( next and previous) that sifts through the images of the pdf and I won't allow saving this way

Comment: How are you going to stop them saving the TIF files?

Comment: I'm not I already figured a way that blocks the image saving so I will preview them as separate images and that way no one can save them. Long story short I'm thinking of creating my own pdf reader

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve this.

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1822346 states:

#### Question:

> I am using Acrobat Reader plugin in my webpage. But due to security
>   reasons i dont want user to save pdf. Is there any way by which i can
>   protect my pdf file from Saving and printing?

#### Answer:

> Saving: Not possible. Printing: You can apply a security policy that
>   prevents it, but keep in mind that many PDF viewers do not respect
>   these policies so getting around it is very easy.